# Read text from clipboard without popup in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I made an extension for myself that I use as unpacked in chrome. The extension goal is to store every copied text into the chrome local storage. Everything works fine. I don't want to use a third-party chrome extension because I don't trust it.

I use: `navigator.clipboard.readText()`

The problem is that whenever I visit a website I get an annoying popup that wants permission to read my clipboard. Question: How can I read text from the clipboard using javascript without the annoying popup?

Edit: Maybe I can use a chrome flag. I'm looking into it now.